# Encountered org.hibernate.StaleStateException in production environment but not integration testing

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Below error is encountered when the scheduled function runs in Spring Boot application, however, there is no problem in my integration test because `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is set to `create-only`, but I could not do the same for production server. I created the table with the following SQL statement. What could be the possible cause for this error ?

**Error**

```
2021-11-23 18:22:37.005  INFO 26620 --- [pool-3-thread-1] com.itsedo.scheduler.ScheduledTasks      : 18:22:37: Resending all failed Delivery Orders... ... ...
Hibernate: insert into FailedDeliveryOrder (ccp_number, date, do_number, is_received, location_from, location_to, material_source, supplier, detail, status, title) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into DeliveryOrder$Product (product_description, quantity, unit_of_measurement, DeliveryOrder_ID, ProductDes_Position) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update DeliveryOrder$Product set DeliveryOrder_ID=?, ProductDes_Position=? where id=?
2021-11-23 18:22:37.036 ERROR 26620 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1]
2021-11-23 18:22:37.054  INFO 26620 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2021-11-23 18:22:37.054 ERROR 26620 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:320) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
HibernateJpaDialect.java:320
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
HibernateJpaDialect.java:244
```

**SQL to create table**

```
CREATE TABLE FAILEDDELIVERYORDER (
    id BIGINT,
    ccp_number VARCHAR(255),
    date VARCHAR(255),
    do_number VARCHAR(255),
    is_received BIT,
    location_from VARCHAR(255),
    location_to VARCHAR(255),
    material_source VARCHAR(255),
    supplier VARCHAR(255),
    detail VARCHAR(255),
    status VARCHAR(255),
    title VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE DeliveryOrder$Product (
    id BIGINT,
    product_description VARCHAR(255),
    quantity VARCHAR(255),
    unit_of_measurement VARCHAR(255),
    deliveryorder_id BIGINT,
    productdes_position INTEGER(10)
);

ALTER TABLE DeliveryOrder$Product
ADD FOREIGN KEY (deliveryorder_id) REFERENCES FAILEDDELIVERYORDER(id);
```

**Scheduled function**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
    public void resendFailedDeliveryOrder() {
        logger.info("{}: Resending all failed Delivery Orders... ... ...", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        // create Delivery Order Object
        List<DeliveryOrder.Product> product = new ArrayList<DeliveryOrder.Product>();
        product.add(new DeliveryOrder.Product());
        DeliveryOrder deliveryOrder = new DeliveryOrder(product);
        FailedDeliveryOrder failedDO_1 = new FailedDeliveryOrder(deliveryOrder);
        failedDeliveryOrderRepository.save(failedDO_1);
    }
```

**FailedDeliveryOrder.java**

```
@Table(name = "FailedDeliveryOrder")
@Entity
public class FailedDeliveryOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Embedded
    private DeliveryOrder deliveryOrder;    

    public FailedDeliveryOrder() {
    }

    public FailedDeliveryOrder(DeliveryOrder deliveryOrder) {
        this.deliveryOrder = deliveryOrder;
    }
    //setter and getter
}
```

**DeliveryOrder.java**

```
public class DeliveryOrder {    
    @Entity
    public static class Product {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        public Product() {}
        // setter and getter
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "DeliveryOrder_ID",
        nullable = false
    )
    @OrderColumn(
        name = "ProductDes_Position",
        nullable = false
    )
    private List<Product> product_descriptions = new ArrayList<Product>();

    public DeliveryOrder() {
    }

    public DeliveryOrder(List<Product> products) {
        this.setProduct_descriptions(products);
    }   

    public List<Product> getProduct_descriptions() {
        return product_descriptions;
    }

    public void setProduct_descriptions(List<Product> product_descriptions) {
        this.product_descriptions = product_descriptions;
    }
}
```